# How to search for object in group list? - Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, groups

When I have a Group Object list created from Group, sometimes this list randomly resorts itself, making the indice Get List Element useless and destroys the tree flow.

I need to isolate an object by name from the Group Object List, regardless of indice, or return the indice with the name of a certain object, and I'm not sure how to do this.

Any tips?

Comment: In the outliner there is a search box in the top right corner. Did you mean that feature? What did you mean by Get List Element?

Comment: The Group Object List node in the Animation nodes addon, creates a list of objects from a group. This list often changes the order arbitrarily, which is not great.

Comment: The Search Node solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Object By Name* node to get the required object. If you want to check if it is in the group, you can use an expression node like this:

[image]

Comment: This is handy. Would a similar system be used to bring out the object the in the group list indice number?

Comment: @Draise Can you elaborate? Not sure I understand what you are saying.

Comment: Say you have object X, Z, and Y. They are part of the Group A

So with AN you get *Group Object List*. It will list it the objects with an indice of 0=X, 1=Z and 2=Y. Great, let's program with those indices. But then, suddenly, Blender will switch the group order, and it may turn out as 0=Z, 1=Y, 3=X, making my indice based system useless.

Comment: So.. I would need to search the list for object "X"  and then result the indice output, then use that indice output as the selecting factor in the tree to process other data to the object I want to apply the data to. 

I don't need it to test if true or not, I need the actual indice number of object "X" in what seems to be a dynamic group object list that changes order randomly.

Comment: @Draise Why don't you just use the search node?

Comment: Had no idea they existed till recently.